# One X Client Many X Servers

Tags: linux, xorg

I have an X client and I would like to display it on many servers (with different IPs), is it possible with X Display?

EDIT:

Simple situation I have in network some hosts:
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3

From host 192.168.0.1 I would like to run 'firefox' and display them (only display! no control from remote hosts) in 192.168.0.2 and in 192.168.0.3.

One solutions that I've found is to use [ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver) to screencast and broadcast it , but it is for sure less efficient then forwarding X, and also doesn't allow to broadcast more than one program.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, I guess, Xlib allows one client to call several `XOpenDisplay`: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html and several `XNextEvent`: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XNextEvent.html loops. But yes, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to display a single Xclient directly on multiple X servers, given how X works.

However you could use something like XMX (An X Protocol Multiplexor) to multiplex a single X session on multiple X servers.

*excerpt from the main website: http://cs.brown.edu/software/xmx/*

> XMX is a standalone utility for sharing an X Window System session on
>   multiple X displays. It allows users to see and interact with the same
>   applications at the same time from different locations. XMX takes
>   advantage of the networked nature of the X Window System by acting as
>   an intermediary between X clients and X servers. In this way, XMX
>   works with any X clients and any X servers, without the need to modify
>   either.
>
> XMX provides a WYSIWIS (What You See Is What I See)
>   environment; it paints the same graphics on all participating
>   displays. The shared client applications appear to each participant in
>   a virtual root window which is subject to local window management. In
>   this way, the shared X session coexists with each user's private X
>   session.
>
> The X client applications which are shared via XMX are unaware that
>   they are being viewed or controlled by more than one user. Existing,
>   single-user X client applications may be shared using XMX without
>   recompilation, relinking or access to source code.

[image]

image of it in action in a lab.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this:

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/x-faq/part6/section-4.html#b

But actually most of these apps were created before 1994, so they're pretty old. For example ShX supports only SPARC, MIPS, sun3 and VAX machines.

XMX was also hard to compile for me.

I think most popular nowadays is [XDMX](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/).